# Processing (the Language) to Javascript, how to load multiple .pde source files with a .java file as well?

Tags: javascript, processing

```
<canvas id=”geometry” data-processing-sources=”ClassFile1.pde ClassFile2.pde main.pde” width=”800″ height=”800″ />
```

Using the above method doesn't work, but it works if the source is only within one .pde and doesn't include a .java file.

Is there anyway to use 4 .pde files and 1 .java file for a Javascript "app"?

http://processingjs.org/
http://processing.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the "using multiple files" part. Processing.js can do that just fine. The problem is that You can't just include .java files and expect it to work. Processing.js runs Processing source code by translating it to native JS and running that on the page. If you use any plain Java, you're no longer using Processing, you're using Java, and all bets are off. Rewrite your .java to real Processing code (usually fairly easy) and turn it into a .pde file, and things should work.

If your code runs in the PDE with just main.pde, ClassFile1.pde, and ClassFile2.pde, and you don't escape to plain Java in your source to do things that you can also do in Processing, then it'll run using Processing.js

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. I converted the .java to .pde, though still no luck. I'm guessing external .jar libraries are a no go, then?

Comment: If so, how do sites like OpenProcessing display their applications?

Comment: as noted on the processing.js articles for P5 and JS devs, imports don't work because .jar files are JVM-compiled bytecode. You'll have to do more work there, by either converting the code used to generate the .jar to Processing code (sometimes easy, sometimes impossible), or using a JavaScript equivalent object that has the same API, included on the page before your sketch starts.

Comment: Alright. I had a feeling, but had some wishful thinking for a out of the box work around. :-) I'm sure openprocessing.org uses Java Applets.

Comment: they certainly used to, although I think plain Processing is starting to push for a .js solution for the web, too (given the slew of security concerns Java in the browser has been racking up).